# How to follow people on twitter using cURL?

Tags: php, http, curl, twitter, request

I'm using cURL to generate HTTP Requests to login to my twitter and I'm trying to follow people using it, one of the problems I'm currently facing is that the follow button doesn't seem to be a form but actually just a button that sends the following request

```
GET https://twitter.com/i/user/follow
Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Request Headers
Accept  image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.8,ar;q=0.6
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
```

What I found weird was that no ID for the user was being passed on to be followed so I have no idea how is it being passed on, I thought maybe from the referer but I tried mimicking the request from my browser by visiting a profile then visiting that URL but I got a 405 error

Does anyone have any idea how does twitter send requests to follow people currently?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is handled using cookie. Somehow you couldn't capture the `Cookie` from the request. Twitter is tracking the login using cookie. That's why the simple GET request works after login, and doesn't work(405 error) where you are not loggedin. The steps are:

Login using curl and store the cookie in a file. Just catch the login request as you caught for follow request.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'user=username&pass=password&someparam=xyz');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'c:/temp/cookie.txt');

curl_close($ch); // don't forget to close curl
```

Now call the http `GET` for the follow request that you posted in description. This time use the cookie that you stored in previous call.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'c:/temp/cookie.txt');
```